# Is there a way to make the textScaleFactor the same everywhere in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to make the textScaleFactor the same everywhere?

I know the way to wrap a MediaQuery for every widget that wants to control the textSacleFactor.

But, it’s not elegant. If I just put the MediaQuery in the MaterialApp, most situations are okay, except using “Navigator.of(context).push” or “showModalBottomSheet” etc.

Do you have any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Overriding your whole app's textScaleFactor is a bad design.

Comment: Yes, I am not going to set the textScaleFactor to a fixed value like 1, just to limit the max value.

Comment: I mean, if the user updated the settings for device's magnification, textScaleFactor will be updated because it depends on that. Else, you don't care for accessibility of your app.

Comment: I know this is not a good design for the user who wants to change the device's magnification, but it's full of text on our app, they can't see the complete text if the textScaleFactor is too large. so, I do this.

Comment: It seems like a design problem to me, not text's scale factor problem. If your app have a lot of text, consider making it scrollable or maybe using FittedBox.

Comment: Actually, I have used FittedBox and SingleChildScrollView to adjust some layout. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin for that https://pub.dev/packages/sizer

use `.sp` to resize

Answer (score 0):

You can use Screen Util for it and just put **.sp** to get it:- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil
Example:

```
Text(
  '16sp,if data is not set in MediaQuery,my font size will change with the system.',
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 16.sp, //<- Here
  ),
),
```